# Can PyCharm autocomplete arguments when instantiating a class?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Is it possible to set up PyCharm to autocomplete arguments when instantiating a class like in the example?

3:48 [Autocomplete arguments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqS8OVULtEo)

Comment: is there any development on that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"ctrl p" will show  parameter info which can be useful to remember what parameters the object takes and the order.

Comment: What version of PyCharm is that for? With 2.6, `Ctrl-P` is mapped to `Show/Hide path text` by default.

Comment: I am using 3.1.3, it is Cmd-P for a mac as far as I know.

Comment: Cheers. I'm surprised they moved from automatic tooltip to manual interaction, though.

Comment: No worries, I have only used pycharm 3 so I had no idea it used to be different.

Comment: In PyCharm 3.4 on Windows, this function seems not to be bound to any hotkey. You can find it in the `View` menu as `Parameter Info`.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm provides this by default. It doesn't inject the argument names into the code as per the video you linked to, but it does give you a tool tip while instantiating a class with the arguments listed.